# jquery ajax call taking too long or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have a form that I want to ensure the paypal email address is valid before I submit. So i am making a jquery submit call like this

```
        $('#new_user').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/validate_paypal",            
                dataType: 'json',
          data: {email : $('#user_paypal_email').val()},
              success: function( data ) {
                if (data.response["valid"] == false){
                        $('#user_paypal_email').closest('.field').addClass('fieldWithErrors');
                        $('#user_paypal_email').append('<span style="color:#E77776;">This is not a valid email address</span>');
                        return false;
               }else{
                        return true;
                 }
                }
        });
```

but the problem is this call thats a second and the page already refreshes before the ajax is complete....if I put the return false at the end of the call I can see my json is correct but for some reason the way I have it now wont finish...any ideas on how to correct this

Comment: It's not "taking too long", it's asynchronous which means that no matter how fast it is you won't get the result until after the form has submitted. You need to either change it to a synchronous call (which means _nothing_ will happen until the result comes back - possibly ugly from the user's point of view) or prevent the default form submission and then submit it yourself once you get your result.

Comment: how do i change it to synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use preventDefault() immediately when the submit event is fired.  Then wait for the response from paypal and then call submit() on the form.

```
$('#new_user').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);  //save reference to form
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/validate_paypal",            
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {email : $('#user_paypal_email').val()},
                success: function( data ) {
                  if (data.response["valid"] == false){
                        $('#user_paypal_email').closest('.field').addClass('fieldWithErrors');
                        $('#user_paypal_email').append('<span style="color:#E77776;">This is not a valid email address</span>');
                        return false;
               }else{
                        form.unbind('submit');  //remove binding
                        form.submit(); //submit form
                 }
                }
        });
```

Comment: @Tamer I updated the answer to remove the binding before submitting so it doesn't keep calling itself.  If you want to make the async call synchronous, then use the ajax setting ' async: false' http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something right away you would need to set async false in the request